# How to retrieve Videos from a YouTube CHANNEL with java gdata client

Tags: java, youtube-api, gdata-api

im using the java google gdata client api for retrieving youtube videos which works fine so far.
But today i faced a problem. Im trying to receive videos from a **channel** but getting no results.
The (example) url of a channel im trying to find videos:
http://www.youtube.com/channel/HCrrUf3dKG1Gw

I tried to use the YouTubeQuery setAuthor method with "HCrrUf3dKG1Gw" (no matter if setPartner was false or true) and setFullTextQuery "PERSONA 4"-> no results

Getting videos from url containing the "user" works fine with setting the author in the query.

Thats the code im using (slightly modified):

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(<clientId>)
service.setConnectTimeout(2000)
YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(new URL(<url>)
query.setOrderBy(YouTubeQuery.OrderBy.RELEVANCE)
query.setTime(Time.ALL_TIME)
query.setFullTextQuery(<query>)
query.setSafeSearch(YouTubeQuery.SafeSearch.NONE)
query.setMaxResults(50)
if (isPartner) {
   query.setUploader(Uploader.PARTNER)
}
if (author) {
   query.setAuthor(<author>)
}
VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class)
List<VideoEntry> videos = videoFeed.getEntries()
```

Does anybody have a clue what im missing here? Are channels different handled than user?

Answer (score 1):

Solve in HTTP URLs first, then consider java API.

When URL ends in "videos", can add query parameters after "?":

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=puppy&safeSearch=none&orderby=viewCount

When URL ends in "channels"/channelID you can't.

On your channel page  http://www.youtube.com/channel/HCrrUf3dKG1Gw type "MODOK" into "Search Channel" box & search. Result page is
http://www.youtube.com/channel/HCrrUf3dKG1Gw/videos?query=MODOK

i.e. before you can add query params, a channel-based URL must look like:

http://www.youtube.com/channel/HCrrUf3dKG1Gw/videos .

Java API generates HTTP URLs and sends them via HTTP-based sockets - identical to above.

**Solution:**

```
 YouTubeQuery query = 
 new YouTubeQuery(new URL("http://www.youtube.com/channel/HCrrUf3dKG1Gw/videos");
```

Comment: Thx @Glen

I tried your suggestion but getting a exception:
  
`com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:text/html;charset=utf-8  
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2136)`    
Does this solution really work for you? If yes: what gdata api version are you using?
Im using the gdata-youtube-2.0 client.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.
URL is wrong. In gdata library calls this one

```
https://GDATA.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels
```

has to be used for channel queries if use Data API 2.0.

And

```
https://GDATA.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos
```

for video queries.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_channel_search

In case of Data API 3.0

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
```

Try this example
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#retrieve_my_uploads